# Windows Task String

Tags: c#, windows, system, external

Please does anyone know how to get the string in the picture in C sharp?
http://janahorova.wz.cz/problem.PNG

I need to know that the application throws error message (system error) but the system error does not have my application as parent process and also it throws exit code zero
I also tried Windows event log but the message was not there

I need exactly this string not process name or process windows title (iterating through windows titles doesnt help because the error apparently doesnt belong to my process - but in the task bar the application name changes to app.exe - system error)

Is there some other way to recognize that external application got System error? (the external applications exit code is 0)

Comment: Can you show some code what you have tried...

Comment: i havent found any way to get the string inside the task bar